# Exception in returning Generic List from WCF

Tags: c#

Hi I am stuck in strange issue,

I have an Generic list `List<Accounts>` it is populated from database, then this list is returning to client.

When list contains more than 3000 items it is throwing exception.

I have set following values in `web.config`

```
maxDepth="2147483647" 
maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
```

Comment: What exception are you receiving?

Comment: There's a good chance you could just simply be hitting a timeout issue. Try to set the timeouts on your binding both on the client and the server to something higher than 1 minute (which is the default)

Comment: Don't forget maxItemsInObjectGraph of the DataContractBehavior.

Answer (score 1):

As Kirk mentioned, try add a behavior to your config similar to below:

```
<behaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="MyService.MyServiceBehavior">
 <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
</behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

If this works for you then don't mark me as correct, Kirk you add an answer and I will remove this one

Answer (score 0):

**Here are some solutions you could try:**

- There’s a good chance you could be hitting a timeout issue. Try to set the timeouts on your binding both on the client and the server to something higher than 1 minute (which is the default).
- Increase maxItemsInObjectGraph in DataContractBehavior.

Otherwise, edit your question to include information about the exception you’re getting and any other information that may be relevant.